# View's collection only working in console.log

Tags: backbone.js

Sorry for the vague title, I'm not sure what's going on enough to formulate it better.

So, this is the render in my view:

```
  render: function () {
    var that = this;
    var template = JST['gists/index'];
    that.$el.html(template);
    console.log(['index to render', that.collection]);
    _.each(that.collection, function (gist) { // <- I set a breakpoint here
      console.log('looping');
      that.appendGistDetail(gist);
    });

    return that;
  },
```

The `console.log(..., that.collection]) is logging this collection correctly:

```
["index to render", child]
  0: "index to render"
  1: child
    _byId: Object
    length: 1
    models: Array[1] // <- Note one element. Saving space, but I checked it out and the model is correct
// Worth noting 'looping' is not being logged
```

However the output from the previously mentioned breakpoint
Scope Variable display in Chrome Dev tools:

```
that: child
  $el: jQuery.fn.jQuery.init[1]
  childViews: Array[0]
  cid: "view2"
  collection: child
    _byId: Object
    length: 0
    models: Array[0] // <- Note it's empty, just to test I also set a bp on the line above and it's the same, and when I hovered my mouse over `that.collection` from `console.log` it also said it was empty, but it logs correctly.
```

So, I'm not really sure what to do, or even what's going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you set a breakpoint here:

```
_.each(that.collection, function (gist) {
```

and see that `that.collection` is empty but your `console.log`:

```
console.log(['index to render', that.collection]);
```

suggests that `that.collection` has one model. I suspect that you're seeing two confusing behaviors at the same time:

1. `console.log` throws a live reference to its arguments into the console, it doesn't take a snapshot of their current state. So, if something changes between the `console.log` call and when you look at the console, you'll see the changed version rather than the one you think you logged.
2. [`Collection#fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) is an AJAX call and *A* stands for *Asynchronous*.

So the sequence of events probably looks like this:

1. You `collection.fetch()` which fires off an AJAX call.
2. You say `v = new View({ collection: collection })` and `v.render()`.
3. `console.log` is hit and a reference to the collection gets stashed in the log.
4. You get to your breakpoint and find an empty collection.
5. The server responds to the AJAX call and the collection gets populated with one model.
6. You look at the console and find a collection with one model in it.
7. Confusion.

The solution is to bind your rendering to events on the collection and make sure your `render` can handle an empty collection in a sensible fashion.

And be careful with using `console.log` to help you debug asynchronous things, you'll have to take your own snapshots (`console.log(collection.toJSON())` for example) if you want consistent and sensible results.

---

PS: `console.log` is a variadic function, you can give it as many arguments as you want:

```
console.log('index to render', that.collection);
```

Also, a collection contains a list of models but it isn't actually the list itself. So doing things like `_.each(collection, ...)` won't spin you through the models, it will spine you through a bunch of internal properties that you probably don't care about. You want to iterate over the models:

```
_.each(collection.models, ....)
```

or better, use the [built-in Underscore methods](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods):

```
collection.each(...)
```

Comment: Yup, that was the exact course of events. What would you advise I bind the render to? reset? I included the `appendDetail` function so I wouldn't have to re-render the whole view every time something new was added. Also, For the record, I originally used the BB method, switching to underscore was a shot in the dark.

Comment: Depends on which version of Backbone you're using and how you call `fetch`. If you're using an older Backbone then `fetch` does a reset so that's the event you want. On newer ones, `fetch` triggers `'add'`, `'remove'`, and `'change'` events unless you `fetch({ reset: true })` to ask for a `'reset'`. You probably want to listen for `'add'`, `'remove'`, `'change'`, and `'reset'` and respond appropriately; then `fetch({ reset: true })` when initializing things to trigger the initial `render`.

Comment: I learned something new today: "console.log throws a live reference to its arguments into the console, it doesn't take a snapshot of their current state. So, if something changes between the console.log call and when you look at the console, you'll see the changed version rather than the one you think you logged."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to loop through each element in the model.  Models have an `attributes` property that allows you to access the data.

If you're using a backbone model:

```
_.each(that.collection.attributes, //...
```

If you're using a backbone collection:

```
_.each(that.collection.models, //...
```

Answer (score 0):

Collection extends some underscore methods - `each` as well.

```
that.collection.each(function (gist) {
  // ...
});
```

Code below does the same thing, but I recommend to use the first one.

```
_.each(that.collection.models, function (gist) {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: I started out with the first way. Despite what console.log is outputting everything else seems to be using the version the Scope Variables is producing, which is an empty array for models.

Comment: Your collection is empty because you fetch a data from the server and this operation is asynchronous. Here you can find more details - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18676344/1104483