# Backbone model .toJSON() doesn't work after .fetch()

Tags: json, backbone.js, fetch

Good day! I need to render a model's attributes to JSON so I can pass them into a template.

Model:

```
var UserInfo = Backbone.Model.extend({
url: appConfig.baseURL + "users/",
});
```

Template:

```
<script type="text/html" class="template" id="profile-form">
    <h2 class="ui-li-heading"><%= username %></h2>
    <p class="ui-li-desc"><strong><%= phone %></strong></p>
</script>
```

View:

```
var ProfilePageView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click #edit': "edit"
    },

    initialize: function () {
        this.template = $.tpl['profile-form'];

        var user = new UserInfo()
        user.fetch({
            data: $.param({email: localStorage.getItem('user_email')}),
            type: 'POST'
        });

        console.log(user) //returns correct object with attrs
        console.log(user.toJSON()) //returns empty object
    },

    render: function (eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
    },

    edit: function () {
        window.workspace.navigate('#account/edit', { trigger: true});
    }
});
```

When i put in console something like this, `user.toJSON()` returns correct data

```
var user = new UserInfo();
user.fetch({
        data: $.param({email: localStorage.getItem('user_email')}),
        type: 'POST'
});
```

But when i put it to my view, its returns `Object {}`.
Where is a mistake or tell me how can differently pass to the template data received from the server in json format? Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [View's collection only working in console.log](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18675885/views-collection-only-working-in-console-log)

Comment: Try in your render method:
  var attributes = this.model.toJSON();
  this.$el.html(this.template(attributes));

Using $el is better as el can be dynamic. Also, the model attribute can be set when the view instance is created:
  var profile = new UserInfo({ id: 1 });
  var profileView = new ProfileView({ model: profile });

It is correct behaviour for Backbone.Model.toJSON to return an object. See the documentation: http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON

Good luck!

Comment: @aphex, you have at least two problems here, you need to use `JSON.stringify()`, and `fetch` is asynchronous. My answer did not originally include the `fetch` issue, I have updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have two problems. `fetch` is asyncronous, so you need to use a callback to use the information.  But first, an explanation about `toJSON`.  `.toJSON()` doesn't actually return a JSON string, it returns an object that is what you want JSON to stringify. This allows you to modify the `toJSON` method to customize what attributes will be taken from your model or collection and added to the JSON string representation of your model.  Here is a quotation from [the Backbone.js docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON):

> **toJSON**  collection.toJSON([options])
>
> Return a shallow copy of the model's attributes for JSON
>   stringification. This can be used for persistence, serialization, or
>   for augmentation before being sent to the server. The name of this
>   method is a bit confusing, as it doesn't actually return a JSON string
>   — but I'm afraid that it's the way that the JavaScript API for
>   JSON.stringify works.

So you should replace this line in your code

```
console.log(user.toJSON())
```

with this one

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(user))
```

The object that you saw was returned by `toJSON` will then be turned into JSON.

Now, even after you do that, it won't work properly, because you will execute the `console.log` before you get the data for your model from `fetch`. `fetch` is asynchronous, so you need to call any code you want to be executed after the `fetch` is done in the `success` callback:

```
    user.fetch({
        data: $.param({email: localStorage.getItem('user_email')}),
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(){
            console.log(user);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(user));
        }
    });
```