# this.collection.each doesn't work during collection render

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

During project development I got necessity in one more collection. So I clone my old collection and set up it. But I got issue, after SUCCESSFULLY fetch(); I try to render collection, but this.collection.each (see below) don't go "inside" of function. Can somebody explain to me, why 2 similar collections with similar code doesn't work similar way?

My old collection include Films data:
Model:

```
var app = app || {};
app.User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        facebook_name: undefined,
        google_name: undefined,
        google_photo: undefined,
        google_url: undefined,
        vk_name: undefined,
        vk_photo: undefined,
        vk_url: undefined,
        local_name: undefined,
        telegram: undefined,
        id: undefined
    },
    parse: function( response ) {
        response.id = response._id;
        return response;
    }
});
```

Model View:

```
var app = app || {};
app.UserView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    className: 'userContainer',
    events: {
    },
    initialize : function() {
        this.template= _.template( $('#userTemplate').html() );
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
        return this;
    }
});
```

Collection:

```
 var app = app || {};
 app.Users = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.User,
    url: '/user/allUsers'
 });
```

Collection View:

```
    var app = app || {};
    app.UsersView = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: '#users',
        events: {},
        initialize: function() {
            this.collection = new app.Users();
            this.collection.fetch();
            this.render();
            //console.log(this.collection);
        },
        render: function() {
              this.collection.each(function(item){
              this.renderUser(item);
          }, this);
        },
        renderUser: function(item) {
            console.log("RenderUser Collection");
            var userView = new app.UserView({
              model: item
            })
            this.$el.append(userView.render().el);
        }
    });
```

Collection-prototype which works fine

```
    var app = app || {};
    app.Film = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            title: 'No name',
            year: 0,
            rated: "Unknown",
            released: 'Unknown',
            runtime: 'Unknown',
            genre: 'Unknown',
            director: 'Unknown',
            writer:'Unknown',
            actors: 'Unknown',
            plot: 'Unknown',
            language: 'Unknown',
            country: 'Unknown',
            awards: 'Unknown',
            poster: 'http://placehold.it/320x150',
            imdbRating: 0,
            imdbVotes: 0,
            imdbID: 'Unknown',
            type: 'Unknown',
            userRate: 0
        },
        parse: function( response ) {
            response.id = response._id;
            return response;
        }
    });
 var app = app || {};
 app.Films = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: app.Film,
    url: '/film/all'
});
    var app = app || {};
    app.FilmView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: 'div',
        className: 'filmContainer',
        events: {
            'click .details': 'details',
            'click .star': 'rate'
        },
        initialize : function() {
            this.template= _.template( $('#filmTemplate').html() );
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ));
            return this;
        }
    });
    var app = app || {};
    app.FilmsView = Backbone.View.extend({
      el: '#films',
      events: {},
      initialize: function() {
        this.collection = new app.Films();
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.render();
      },
      render: function() {
        this.collection.each(function(item) {
          this.renderFilm(item);
        }, this);
      },
      renderFilm: function(item) {
        var filmView = new app.FilmView({
          model: item
        })
        this.$el.append(filmView.render().el);
      }
    });
```

---

Solved my problem this way:

```
this.collection.fetch({
    success: function(){
        this.render();
    }.bind(this)
});
```

Thanks to [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) for hints.

Comment: Executive summary: `fetch` is an AJAX call, you have to listen for events (or use promises or `fetch` callbacks or...) before you can know that `fetch` has finished.

Comment: de-bug process show, that in the moment when I want to render(), collection is full of data. I add example of collection which works fine.

Comment: Your debugging process is making invalid assumptions about how `console.log` behaves: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18676344/479863. If `app.FilmsView` is working then it is working purely by accident and lucky timing.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and advices. Now I clearly understand how console.log() and fetch() works.

Comment: You're welcome, this stuff is a bit weird when you're not used to it.